# Has this problem been studied?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question

Today in Italy all students under 18 faced with a test used to establish the quality of the schools they are in. I read one of the question (a mathematical question, of course!) that make me thing for a while. Here is the question:

**"Prove or disprove that $n^2 + n + 1$ is a prime number for all positive integers n."**

After a while, you are easily convinced that there are some $n$ such that $n^2+n+1$ is not prime. Indeed, taking $n=4$, we get $n^2+n+1 = 21 = 3 \cdot 7$, which is not prime.

This reading made me think about this problem:

**What properties do all $n$, such that $n^2+n+1$ is prime, share?**

or equivalently

**What properties do all $n$, such that $n^2+n+1$ is not prime, share?**

The problem has a really simple formulation and then I start wondering that someone already studied this. Is it true? Are there some references about it?

Comment: $n^2 + n + 41$ is a fun example that works for $n < 41$.

Comment: @naslundx really awesome! is there a proof?

Comment: it is a very known polynomial, if you search prime generating polynomials you'll find more informations

Comment: Can you please provide a link for the whole test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Questions about prime numbers and polynomials along the lines of your first question tend to be deep, and consequently very hard. One such question, a special case of the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), asks whether the polynomial $n^2+1$ assumes infinitely many prime values; we don't have an answer. The current state of mathematical understanding is far removed from being able to answer your first question.

Your second question is easier to attack: we *can* classify some of the ways in which the polynomial $n^2+n+1$ fails to output primes, using modular arithmetic. More specifically, if you can find a number $d$ and a root of the polynomial $n^2+n+1$ modulo $d$ then you have found an infinite (linear) family of outputs of the polynomial which are not prime. For example,

1. $n\equiv1\bmod3\implies3\mid n^2 + n + 1$.
2. $n\equiv 2\bmod7$ or $n\equiv4\bmod7$ $\implies7\mid n^2+n+1$.